# Can a positive function defined on a closed interval have $0$ as an inf?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a positive real function on $[a, b] $. The $\inf$ of $f$ is thus well-defined.

Can it be $0$?

It is not for a continuous function,  but I don't know in the
general case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let
$$f(x)=x-a,\quad x\in (a,b]\quad \text{and}\quad f(a)=1$$

Comment: Very nice, Sami!

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(x)=x-a$? here $\inf f = 0$, and $sup f = b-a$

Also what did you mean by "it's not for a continuous function"

Comment: And $f(a)=0$, therefore the function is not positive.

Comment: If $f$ was continuous, $\inf f=\min f$ since the domain of $f$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ can be non-continuous, then yes, the inf can be $0$. Find a $c\in (a, b)$, and let $f$ be decreasing on $[a, c)$, closing in on $0$ (i.e. $f(x) = c - x$). Then on $[c, b]$ set $f(x) = 1$. Then the inf is $0$, even though it never reaches $0$.